# Putting data from a jsonobject into a gridview

Tags: java, android, json, gridview

i just wondering how to put values i retrieve from a json file, into a gridview, and then this gridview is in my custom adapter. at all times there will only be 6 id's which correspond to an image and 6 names in the gridview.

Here is my code;

```
private TextView tvData;
private ImageView imgtest;
String ChampionName;
String ChampionNameInLowerCase;
String item2;
String item3;
private ListView Championinfo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    imgtest = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    // http://api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko/
    new JSONTask().execute("http://api.champion.gg/champion/ekko/");

    Championinfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Layoutmodel>> {
    @Override
    protected List<Layoutmodel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(finalJson);
            List<Layoutmodel> LayoutModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {


                JSONObject finalObject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                Layoutmodel layoutmodel = new Layoutmodel();
                layoutmodel.setChampionName2(finalObject.getString("key"));
                layoutmodel.setRole(finalObject.getString("role"));

                ChampionName = finalObject.getString("key");
                String role = finalObject.getString("role");
                String items = finalObject.getString("items");

                JSONObject ItemArray = new JSONObject(items);
                item2 = ItemArray.getString("mostGames");
                JSONObject ItemArray2 = new JSONObject(item2);
                item3 = ItemArray2.getString("items");

                JSONArray jsonarray2 = new JSONArray(item3);
                StringBuffer TestBuffer = new StringBuffer();


                List<Layoutmodel.itemname> itemlist = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray2.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(j);

                    Integer ID = finalObject2.getInt("id");
                    String ItemName = finalObject2.getString("name");
                    TestBuffer.append(ID + "-" + ItemName + "\n");

                    Layoutmodel.itemname ItemNames = new Layoutmodel.itemname();
                    ItemNames.setName(ItemName);
                }
                layoutmodel.setItemnames(itemlist);
                layoutmodel.setRole(role);
                layoutmodel.setChampionName2(ChampionName);
                LayoutModelList.add(layoutmodel);

                return LayoutModelList;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Layoutmodel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        LayoutAdapter adapter2 = new LayoutAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.rows, result);
        Championinfo.setAdapter(adapter2);




    }

}
```

public class LayoutAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
    private List<Layoutmodel> LayoutModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public LayoutAdapter(Context context2, int resource, List<Layoutmodel> objects) {
        super(context2, resource, objects);
        LayoutModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position2, View convertView2, ViewGroup parent2) {
        if (convertView2 == null) {
            convertView2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
        }
        ImageView imageofchamp;
        TextView nameofchamp;
        TextView position;
        GridView champitems;

        // imageofchamp = (ImageView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        nameofchamp = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        position = (TextView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.smalltxt);
       // champitems = (GridView) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        nameofchamp.setText(LayoutModelList.get(position2).getChampionName2());
        position.setText(LayoutModelList.get(position2).getRole());


        return convertView2;

    }
}
```

}

Here is what the code returns at the moment;
[image]
and here is the layout of the image above
[image]

and here is the code where i actually get the id and name of items from the json,

```
 for (int j = 0; j < jsonarray2.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject finalObject2 = jsonarray2.getJSONObject(j);

                Integer ID = finalObject2.getInt("id");
                String ItemName = finalObject2.getString("name");
                TestBuffer.append(ID + "-" + ItemName + "\n");

                Layoutmodel.itemname ItemNames = new Layoutmodel.itemname();
                ItemNames.setName(ItemName);
            }
```

Comment: You are not getting gridview ?

Comment: So you would like to recreate what's on the last picture?

Comment: Yes I would @DanielK

Comment: Did you pull ChampName & position off the JSON as well?

Comment: Yes i did @DanielK

Comment: Okay do you know how to pull the rest off the JSON? If I asked you to post that data in Log statements, could you do that?

Comment: Like this for eg, Log.v("ChampName", ChampionName); and Log.v("items", TestBuffer.toString()); @DanielK

Comment: Okay good, does your layout `rows` have IDs for all the sub items?

Comment: @DanielK i havent done this, because there will be many different types ids, which come from multiple json files,  eg api.champion.gg/champion/Ekko and http://api.champion.gg/champion/annie

Comment: I don't mean the JSON response, I mean the layout XML itself. Can you post R.layout.rows?

Comment: @DanielK Here you go - http://pastebin.com/nn9QnMse

Comment: @Kripzy Okay is there a reason why you can't use a linear layout with a few textviews instead? With a gridview, you would have to use a single gridview item & repeat it 6 times. Seems more cumbersome.

Comment: yeah i can do that, but its getting the individual names of items from the json which still troubles me. Could i just make 6 different getJSONObject to retrieve the 6 different positions in the array which has the data?

Comment: @Kripzy I see your question now. Okay your data is pretty large & deep so what exactly do you need from it? Because you have one Champion giving you three roles & you only have space for one role in your current layout. If you're just interested in the "top" role then what data do you want from it? I don't play LoL so I am not sure what you want to extract. Let me know.

Comment: Sorry been a bit disctracted, i have done what i wanted however, the other question i have for you which you brought up, how do make all of the positions show up, other than just top, so the other roles fill my listview - http://i.imgur.com/HqpVi5V.png @DanielK

Comment: @Kripzy Well that depends on how you want to display that information. Do you want to display them in different activities? or the same one?

Comment: I would like to keep it in the single activity @DanielK

Comment: Without modifying your current layout, you could use fragments. Your activity would become a fragment & you could put the roles in a setting & then the user chooses the role & the fragment reloads the data for that role.

Comment: i was thinking something like this, would a tabbed activity do trick? however i've never played around with a tabbed activity so i may need to find some examples!

Comment: @Kripzy Yeah it's the same idea but using tabs instead of a setting which also gives you a cleaner look so go with that. I'll link a pretty good tutorial as an answer so you can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display all three roles, use a tabbed activity with fragments. [Here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ActionBar-Tabs-with-Fragments) is a pretty thorough, up to date tutorial on how to implement that. You already know how to pull the `JSON` data off your object, so you just have to do that 3 times, one for each role.

Comment: i was looking at this, and i realised i forgot to mention something pretty key, i have to do this for 130 champions, im going to have to just stack each roles on top of each other

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. Ideally you go back to a previous activity, that activity would contain the list of champions, then the user would choose a champion, like echo, and your tabbed activity would just query the server again and process the data like we discussed. At the most, you would just have to modify the ASyncTask to take a parameter for the name of the champion the user picked in the previous activity.